# How to compile coffeescript to the parent directory of the source?

Tags: node.js, compiler-construction, coffeescript, cakefile

I just got into the world of caffeine and I'm having a bit of trouble with Cakefiles.

It is my understanding that Cakefiles use the coffee script syntax; if I want to look for a file in child directories, I need to require the `fs` module and do whatever I need to do as if I'm in a nodejs app right? And I need only one Cakefile for the whole project, correct? Do I need to make any changes to package.json or anything to the project to use Cakefile?

That being said, as I was looking at some examples at [this delicious cakefile tutorial](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/%5BHowTo%5D-Compiling-and-Setting-Up-Build-Tools) I have come across this following snippet:

```
{exec} = require 'child_process'
task 'build', 'Build project from src/*.coffee to lib/*.js', ->
  exec 'coffee --compile --output lib/ src/', (err, stdout, stderr) ->
    throw err if err
    console.log stdout + stderr
```

I wanted to put my coffescripts under `/coffee` directory and I wanted them to compile to `/` for each coffee script it found. For example if it found `routes/coffee/index.coffee` the compiled js should be outputted as `routes/index.js`. In order to do that I tried running `$ coffee --output ../ .` but since it didn't work --although I thought it was worth the try-- I tried doing that with Cakefile.

```
{exec} = require 'child_process'
task 'build', 'Build project from *.coffee to ../*.js', ->
  exec 'coffee --compile --output ../ .', (err, stdout, stderr) ->
    throw err if err
    console.log stdout + stderr
```

Which is the altered version of the snippet above. It didn't work as well. I'm trying to learn more about cakefiles so that I can maybe write a function that rememberes the pwd and goes up one directory, sets output as that directory while it is compiling coffee scripts.

If you could lead me to a solution or a source that could help me find the solution I would appreciate it. However please keep in mind that I do not understand the advanced coffee-script stuff from the documentations... Examples with results would be more useful for my skills in development.

Comment: _"`$ coffee --output ../ .` but since it didn't work"_ What happened instead of what you expect?

Comment: oh I found the output now, it put the `/coffee/script.coffee` into `../coffee/script.js` so it is out of the project directory now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the key difference here is the working directory.

```
- root
-- lib
--- foo.js <- target
-- src
--- foo.coffee
```

When you have that setup, and from `root`, you run `coffee --compile --output lib/ src/` it works because `root/lib` and `root/src` are both easily found from `root`.

```
- root
-- foo.js <- target
-- coffee
--- foo.coffee
```

Now, from `root` when you run `coffee --compile --output ../ ./` then you set the output directory to `root/..` and the input directory to `root/.` (or simply `root`.)

Which means, when you run this command from `root` you want simply:

```
coffee --compile --output ./ coffee/
```

Or if you `cd coffee/`, then this:

```
cd coffee
coffee --compile --output ../ ./
```

Should work fine.

Comment: ahh excellent! thank you! So there is no need to use filesystem modules or anything!

Comment: Not if you just want to run the coffee command. `Cakefile`s are still handy though. You can wrap that line up in a takes and call it with `cake compile` so you don't have to remember the syntax.

Comment: I understand. To make the `--output` folder relative to the `source.coffee` that is being compiled, I need to write a function (maybe one that gets all `.coffee` files into an array and gets their paths, and sets `--output` to `pwd/../` then compiles).